# range function with step size of power of 2 and increase number of zeros in tens position

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Plot the performance of your program scale with N? For this, run your program multiple times and take the minimum time taken for a given value of N for the plot. You can use the value range of `N` = 10,20,40,80, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 10000 and so on.
How can use the value `range()` of python for `N` = 10,20,40,80, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 10000 and so on.

```
numbers_sizes = (i*exp for exp in range(2, 10,2) for i in range(10, 10000,10*2))
```

but this not provide the required answer

Comment: I can't understand the question... but if you wanna add zeros to the number(like the title say), you can use zfill. like '1'.zfill(4) >>>'0001'

Comment: need more description.

Answer (score 0):

integer division and some modulo arithmetic

```
[10**(1+i//4)*2**(i%4) for i in range(15)]
Out[179]: 
[10,
 20,
 40,
 80,
 100,
 200,
 400,
 800,
 1000,
 2000,
 4000,
 8000,
 10000,
 20000,
 40000]
```

if you are really 'racing' and doing math with powers of 2 then sometimes binary ops are compiled slightly more compactly, may execute faster

```
import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('[10**(1+i//4)*2**(i%4) for i in range(100)]', number=1000)
Out[197]: 0.06518084562951763


[10**(1+(i>>2))<<(i & 3) for i in range(15)]

timeit.timeit('[10**(1+(i>>2))<<(i & 3) for i in range(100)]', number=1000)
Out[199]: 0.04540084575825176
```

Answer (score -2):

enter the number 5 and print 1 3 6 10 15 using range() function